# Text disappearing off page?

Tags: vertical-alignment, indentation

I am trying to put some items into a numbered list, and I know that to do this, I need to use the `enumerate` environment. However, when I do this with the following code, the text within the list appears halfway off the page to the left?

I am confused as to what could be causing this, as I have followed the directions for using the `enumerate` environment.

The code I have is as follows:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item[$Q$, the set of states]
\item[$\Sigma$, the alphabet for that machine]
\item[$\delta$, the transition function]
\item[$q_0 \in Q$, the starting state]
\item[$F \subseteq Q$, the set of final states]
\end{enumerate}
```

This also happens with this code, although not to the same degree. Here, the text is still on the page, but is indented past the text which I have designated with the `noindent` command.

```
\noindent Types of proof: 
\begin{enumerate}
\item[Construction]
\item[Contradiction]
\item[Induction]
\end{enumerate} \newline
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `[...]` like this, those are an optional argument to give a custom label, so instead of 1. 2. 3. It's printing your list item. Get rid of the square brackets

Comment: Ah, thank you. I haven't done this in a while.

Answer (score 3):

Since it appears that you don't wish to create an enumeration, you shouldn't be using an `enumerate` environment. Instead, use a `description` environment -- and pile less material into the label. If you need math material in the label to be in **bold**, load the `enumitem` package and provide the environment option `before=\mathversion{bold}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[before=\mathversion{bold}]
\item[$Q$] the set of states
\item[$\Sigma$] the alphabet for that machine
\item[$\delta$] the transition function
\item[$q_0 \in Q$] the starting state
\item[$F \subseteq Q$] the set of final states
\end{description} 
\end{document}
```